# IBM MQ message channel is not coming up

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to setup message channel on IBM MQ v8.

I am running IBM MQ Server 8.x on Ubuntu Linux.

I have 2 queue managers QM1, and QM2.

On QM1, I have created a Sender Channel, and on QM2, I have created a Receiver channel.

## On QM1:

**Remote queue definition**

```
DEFINE QREMOTE(RMQ1) DESCR('Remote queue for QM2') REPLACE +
PUT(ENABLED) XMITQ(QM2)  RNAME(Q_ON_QM2) RQMNAME(QM2)
```

**Transmission queue definition**

```
DEFINE QLOCAL(QM2) DESCR('Transmission queue to QM2') REPLACE +
USAGE(XMITQ) PUT(ENABLED) GET(ENABLED) TRIGGER TRIGTYPE(FIRST) +
TRIGDATA(QM1.TO.QM2) INITQ(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ)
```

**Sender channel definition for a TCP/IP connection:**

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(QM1.TO.QM2) CHLTYPE(SDR) TRPTYPE(TCP) +
REPLACE DESCR('Sender channel to QM2') XMITQ(QM2) +
CONNAME('127.0.0.1(**1491**)') //-- QM2's listener is on 1490
```

**On 2nd Queue manager (QM2)**

**Local queue definition**

```
DEFINE QLOCAL(Q_ON_QM2) REPLACE PUT(ENABLED) GET(ENABLED) +
DESCR('Local queue ')
```

**Receiver channel definition**

**For a TCP/IP connection:**

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(QM1.TO.QM2) CHLTYPE(RCVR) TRPTYPE(TCP) +
REPLACE DESCR('Receiver channel from QM1')
```

At the end of configuration, my sender channel remains in "Retrying" state, and Receiver channel remains in "inactive" state.

How do I get this channel running?

Comment: You should take a look at the error log on both the sender and receiver QMs, that should tell you the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, it appears the problem is with your port. 
The conname for connection should specify the port where the listener is actually running.  Is it 1491 or 1490?

CONNAME('127.0.0.1(**1491**)') //-- QM2's listener is on 1490

Verify the listener is running for the receiving qmgr and specify that port in your conname.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons of a sender channel going in retrying state.

**1. Wrong parameters.**

Check connection name as Valerie suggested. Make sure IP address and port number points to the receiver queue manager.

**2. Transmission queue unavailable.**

Make sure the transmission queue is available. Note: Sometimes the transmission queue will be available but it ***might be GET disabled,*** in that case also the sender channel will go in retrying state. The sender channel opens the transmission queue in exclusive mode, which means if the transmission queue is opened by another application (say RFHUTIL), then the sender channel will not be able to access transmission queue and hence the channel will go in retrying state. So, make sure the transmission queue is not opened by some other application.

**3. Receiver channel unavailable.**

This could be the case when the receiver queue manager is down.
Also, make sure the name of receiver channel is same as the sender channel(which seems correct in your case).

**4. Receiver channel and sender channel go out of sequence**

The receiver channel and sender channel maintains a sequence number for message transmission. Due to environmental issues like network glitches, the sequence number might become inconsistent between the sender and receiver channel.

**RESET** your sender and receiver channels to overcome this issue.

Comment: While you first three answers are great, 4) is not correct. Sequence number error is a sign that something very bad has happened, and is never a result of a network glitch. Advise to simply RESET and carry on without any investigation could result in message loss or duplication.

Comment: @MoragHughson As per my experience, whenever we have seen sequence issue is when someone abruptly stops sender/receiver channel and the messages were still being transmitted. Mostly we do a channel RESET without much fear of loss of messages. Well, if there is a sequence issue, the sender channel will go in retrying state and messages will be piling up in the transmission queue which has most likely become GET disabled. I don't see any reason of message loss, unless there is an uncommitted message left in txn queue which is not coming back to the queue even after the queue is not open

Comment: @MoragHughson Could you please provide some other scenarios where message loss can happen?

Comment: If your channel ends are out of sequence, it is the channel telling you that the other end attempted to send a message sequence number that wasn't what it expected. If you tell it to RESET, and thus ignore the sequence number problem, the missing messages would never been sent. If your sequence number errors are as a result of deleting state at one end or the or, I.e. one of the two reported numbers is 1, then you're more likely to be safe because the error is as a result of a queue manage delete or a channel delete. All other situations should be investigated.